# android emulator [xcb] error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I've recently installed `Ubuntu 14.04` and i'm trying to get the android emulator started in it. It had another problem before: it was complaining that it can't find `libGL.so`. so I ran the following command and that error was solved:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

But right after that I get the following error:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
emulator64-arm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

A search revealed that it's c thread related but I have no idea how to fix it.
Any suggestion is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is a premission issue if then it is enough simply to put the folder of the sdk on the main hard drive and change the permissions of the folder with

```
chmod -R +x android-sdk-linux
```